# How can I find all the members of a Properties.Resources in C#

Tags: c#, resources, properties

I have some resources in a C# Assembly which I address by

```
byte[] foob = Properties.Resources.foo;
byte[] barb = Properties.Resources.bar;
...
```

I would like to iterate through these resources without having to keep an index of what I have added. Is there a method that returns all the resources?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: It turns out they're properties rather than fields, so:

```
foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(Properties.Resources).GetProperties
    (BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", property.Name, property.GetValue(null, null));
}
```

Note that this will also give you the "ResourceManager" and "Culture" properties.

Comment: isn't it slower than accessing directly the resources through GetManifestResource* ?

Comment: They do different things. For one thing, you may have content in the assembly which isn't in `Properties.Resources`, and secondly this gives you individual resources instead of resource *files*. If you have two string resources, for example, they may both be in the same resource file - finding the resource names means loading the file and then asking for the names within that file etc.

Comment: In other words, this answer does what the question specifically asked for :)

Answer (score 2):

Try `Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()`. Call it like this:

```
Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceNames()
```

Edit: To actually get the resource call `Assembly.GetManifestResouceStream()` or to view more details use `Assembly.GetManifestResourceInfo()`.

Answer (score 0):

`CampingProfile`  is the resource file

```
var resources =  CampingProfile.ResourceManager.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, true, true);
foreach (DictionaryEntry resource in resources)
{
    ;
}
```

This give you all properties into the resource file without the others properties