# C# Iterating through the images in the Resource folder

Tags: c#, resources

My idea is to make a search engine which will search through all the images from the projects Resource folder.
I would like to know how to get hold of the File-name of all images, save them in a list and then show the search results in a picturebox?

The biggest issue is retrieving the names of all images, i know how to do the rest.

Comment: I think it might help if you state which language and platform you want this for!

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1310812/how-can-i-find-all-the-members-of-a-properties-resources-in-c